# In Chrome 90, ctrl+c often opens DevTools instead of copying

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Editing Javascript code in Chrome version 90 on a Chromebook, it happens often (but not always!) that ctrl+c results in the opening of DevTools, instead of copying text. At the same time all Javascript code is selected, turning it into blue.

This does not happen when clicking Copy in the right-click menu.

Comment: Are you also pressing the "Shift" key? Ctrl+Shift+C opens the dev tools.

Comment: No, I don't. Just ctrl-c.

Comment: Iván, you pointed me to the solution.  When I just press Shift, Chrome seems to remember this.It shows Ctrl, Alt, Shift and Search vertically in the top left corner, and in this case Shift is highlighted. I don't know how to get rid of this.  After that, when pressing ctrl+c it understands that I want to do Ctrl+Shift+c.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: The problem is solved (see https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/5163341/each-time-i-type-any-of-the-ctrl-alt-shift-search-key-a-small-panel-slide-out-from-top-left-side?hl=en). Thanks, Iván!